# Modeling hair strand diffraction?

Tags: optics, diffraction

It's well known that a human hair can diffract light (plenty of demos out there, all you need is a laser pointer and a strand of hair). I've been thinking, however: how can one model this process? The resulting diffraction pattern is pretty similar to that of a single slit (logical, since it's a single hair). However, the hair is blocking light, not letting it through like a screen would. I think it's reasonable to assume therefore an intensity profile at $z=0$ *opposite* to that of a single slit, assuming the strand has a diameter $d$:

$$I(x)=0 \ \ -d/2<x<d/2 \ ; \ I_0 \ \mathrm{elsewhere}.$$

It's "opposite" since a slit would have $I=1$ within the slit, and $0$ elsewhere. In this notation, I'm ignoring the vertical axis, but it can be accounted for assuming that the hair has length $L$. Do you think this is reasonable? Calculating the Fraunhofer diffraction integral seems to yield a cosine squared distribution.

Comment: Babinet's Principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet%27s_principle or https://physicsopenlab.org/2021/01/21/light-diffraction-and-babinet-principle/ is exactly what you need to get the relationship between diffraction by a slit in a mask and diffraction by a complementary obstruction like a hair.

Comment: @Buzz Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Relevant: ["Differences between single-slit/obstacle diffraction"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227687/145491)